# Apache2 and logrotate: delaycompress needed?

Tags: apache-2.2, compression, logrotate

I am currently looking at the file size of my Apache logs as they became huge. In my logrotate configuration, I have `delaycompress` enabled. Does Apache really need this (as the logrotate documentation says that some programs still write in the old file) or is it safe to disable `delaycompress`?

Here is my logrotate configuration:

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
    weekly
    missingok
    rotate 26 
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 640 root adm
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
            if [ -f /var/run/apache2.pid ]; then
                    /etc/init.d/apache2 restart > /dev/null
            fi
    endscript
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're doing an Apache restart (or even 'graceful') it will close open file handles and open them again. You shouldn't need delaycompress because the file will have been closed and re-opened as part of your postrotate restart.

```
rotate access_log -> access_log.1 (rename action, no INODE change)
apache still writing to access_log.1 (same open FD on same INODE)
apache restart (close FD, release INODE writing)
apache writing to access_log (new FD to a new INODE)
```

A restart is kind of a bad idea - what if the config file accidentally changed and is no longer valid? Your apache won't start back up. Instead send a HUP to the parent process which tells it to close/re-open file handles.

```
postrotate
  /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/apache2.pid 2>/dev/null` 2>/dev/null || true
endscript
```

cat will fail if the PID is missing (or empty, or invalid) causing kill to also fail so you don't need the `if..then` block around it.

Comment: YMMV but I find this a nice answer

Answer (score 0):

Hrm, in this case, probably, as Apache keeps the logs open.

One thing you can try is the `rotatelogs` script. It's part of the `apache2-utils` package, at least here on my Ubuntu workstation.  Another approach would be to rotate them daily instead of weekly, so you're buffering less before compression.

Comment: Probably should have added my logrotate config in the above question - as postrotate I have set up a restart of apache2.